# I can't change CSS attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I try to change css attribute with Jquery. I do

```
wrapperInner.css('overflow', 'visible');
```

but value still stay the same. I do alert `alert(wrapperInner.css('overflow'))` and it shows `hidden`.
Here is  css for this

```
.tribe-events-calendar td div.wrapper div.wrapper_inner {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden!important;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!important` is overriding the jQuery. Remove it.

Using `!important` is sloppy and generally a bad idea—you are seeing how it causes problems.

If you can't remove it, add a class with the styles you need:

```
var thing = $('div')   
thing.addClass('shown');
```

```
div {
    color: red !important;
}

.shown {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

I used colors, but the concept applies. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akpy7/)

​

Comment: give it also an !important? wrapperInner.css('overflow', 'visible !important');

Comment: Updated my answer based on not being able to remove `!important`